# Validate nested request dto

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation

I have a request dto:

```
public class Animals {
    private String type;

    @Min(value = 1, message = "Value must be between 1 and 10”)
    @Max(value = 10, message = "Value must be between 1 and 10”)
    private Integer fingers;
}
```

Validations are working fine on following controller:

```
public void animalFingers(@Valid @RequestBody List<Animals> animals) {
    log.info("Request received: {}", animals);
}
```

I have another request dto like:

```
public class PetAnimal extends HashMap<String, @Valid List<Animals>>{
}
```

And validations(on animal's fingers' range) aren’t working on:

```
public String getAnimalWithFingers(@Valid @RequestBody PetAnimal petAnimals) {
    log.info("Request received: {}", petAnimals);
}
```

How to fix this?

P.S. I have tried to simplify the example, but my request dto needs to be a map only. basically my request dto can't change.